# I don't know if I am using the correct selectors

Tags: css, wordpress

I've just begun making some simple changes to a Wordpress site. I would like for the bottom padding of arrows within a toggle element to be larger so that the text will respect a"margin".

I have copied the selectors by inspecting the element, but there is nothing happening when I actually paste it in my WordPress and save it. ¿Could you help me know which is the correct selector for the triangles?

I though it was this:

```
  #elementor-tab-title-4601 .elementor-toggle-icon-opened .i {
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

[image: Image to what I would like to move (There shouldn't be text directly beneath the arrow)]

The page is: https://dayston.com.mx/areas-de-practica/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display: flex` to that parent container that houses the text and arrow like this:

```
.elementor-tab-title {
    display: flex;
}
```

And here's the screenshot:

[image]

If you like to learn more about FlexBox, try using this site : https://flexboxfroggy.com/

Comment: IT WORKED!!! I HADN'T THOUGHT OF THAT!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!